# Float Div to Right and Left like Message Convo

Tags: html, css

I have this simple div container which would act as the convo viewer just like in most chatbox today. The sender's message would be displayed stick to the right side, while the recipient's is on the left.

This is the container for the sender's message:

```
<div id = "convo_ins_design">
   <div id = "convo_ins_sent">
     Content goes here
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#convo_ins_design{
  margin: 1.7vh;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

#convo_ins_sent {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  padding: 1vh;
  float: right;
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

When given enough text:
[image]

It's good. But when given longer texts, it starts to break and wanders off course:
[image]

I just want it to look like this:
[image]

And when the text gets longer, the whitebox/container should just extend vertically, not extends horizontally on the left infinitely.

Comment: Your image is breaking because of the fact it's one long word. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an explicit `max-width` for the container and use `word-wrap`. Otherwise the container will just take whatever width it needs to fit the content you give it and it will end up overflowing like your example. I set 100px as an example. You should change that to what works best for your situation.

```css
#convo_ins_design{
  margin: 1.7vh;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

#convo_ins_sent {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  padding: 1vh;
  float: right;
  max-width: 100px; /* ADDED (make this value whatever is best)*/
  word-wrap: break-word; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div id = "convo_ins_design">
   <div id = "convo_ins_sent">
     Hi
   </div>
   <div id = "convo_ins_sent">
     Content
   </div>
   <div id = "convo_ins_sent">
     Content goes here
   </div>
   <div id = "convo_ins_sent">
     Lots more content goes here and it should grow vertically instead of horizontal
   </div>
</div>
```